# How to print DataFrame to multiple Excel sheets in groups of two?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I would like your help printing a DataFrame into groups of 2 to multiple Excel sheets.

Here is an example of a DataFrame:

```
Name     Age

Dale      23
Steve     27
Helen     34
Becky     19
Todd      41
Frank     29
```

I would like the following output please:

Excel sheet 1:

```
Name     Age

Dale      23
Steve     27
```

Excel sheet 2:

```
Name      Age
Helen     34
Becky     19
```

Excel sheet 3:

```
Name      Age
Todd      41
Frank     29
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for any help that you may offer.

Answer (score 2):

Split dataframe to chunks and loop over chunks to create  excel.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import ExcelWriter

dataframe_list = np.split(df,len(df)/2)
xls_path = "<some_path>/output.xlsx"
with ExcelWriter(xls_path) as writer:
    for idx, df in enumerate(dataframe_list):
        df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=f"sheet_{idx+1}",index=False)
    writer.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

First you can split the dataframe into chunks

```py
df_new1, df_new2 = df.iloc[:2, :], df.iloc[2:4, :]
```

Then you can do

```py
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df_new1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
df_new2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet2')
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution, using `groupby`

```
import pandas as pd

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('excel_file.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

for i, dfg in df.groupby(df.index // 2):
    dfg.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'Sheet{i+1}', index=False)

writer.save()
```